# Cardano java lib

Tags: utxo, java, output

Can someone help me understand the below error message better. It first started appearing about 2 months ago when I mint tokens, and I cant seem to get to the bottom of it. I understand the `BabbageOutputTooSmallUTxO` to mean the output is from the tx is too small (ie. not enough input). The annoying thing is it worked well not that long ago

```
[cardano-wallet.wallet-engine:Error:9588] [2022-09-07 11:12:19.67 UTC] 9351a932: Transaction ef626e5b failed: ErrSubmitTxNetwork (ErrPostTxValidationError "TxValidationErrorInMode (ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraBabbage (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (UtxoFailure (BabbageOutputTooSmallUTxO [((Addr Testnet (KeyHashObj (KeyHash \"d27f32....b0ae3\")) (StakeRefBase (KeyHashObj (KeyHash \"ca75b4....44af711c\"))),Value 172400 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash \"e89fd72....cdfdd5\"},fromList [(5275626265724d616e,1)])]),NoDatum,SNothing),Coin 1159390)]))])) BabbageEraInCardanoMode")
```

I have tested the transaction on Blockfrost and Cardano Wallet API and both produce the same error.

I am using https://cardano-client.bloxbean.com Java library to build the transaction using the methods suggested in the documentation and here https://satran004.medium.com/cardano-client-lib-minting-a-new-native-token-in-java-part-iii-1a94a21cfeeb

This is my decompiled transaction

```json
{
    "burn": {
        "tokens": []
    },
    "certificates": [],
    "collateral": [],
    "collateral_outputs": [],
    "deposits_returned": [],
    "deposits_taken": [],
    "fee": {
        "quantity": 186929,
        "unit": "lovelace"
    },
    "id": "91d16f5c982b401b7c3d039c3bc8b213eea97f6dfbfc0b311682facf34e1627c",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "address": "addr_test1qql63uhskkchjsy74kjyx9tk8azsl9gfjxfk8rarnvsshn3sl2jjsnfkffuhuuug5vywcyh0704hpyldjrzjacts4qpqa40yu4",
            "amount": {
                "quantity": 500000000,
                "unit": "lovelace"
            },
            "assets": [],
            "derivation_path": [
                "1852H",
                "1815H",
                "0H",
                "0",
                "0"
            ],
            "id": "d5432926ad3397aeef7b4287ef6eb09a236e7484a8b7d88ad747e72814333b19",
            "index": 0
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "721": {
            "map": [
                {
                    "k": {
                        "string": "version"
                    },
                    "v": {
                        "string": "1.0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "k": {
                        "string": "2037e837ffb5536a8795f493ed14c1f91fc9130df3466386750168a1"
                    },
                    "v": {
                        "map": [
                            {
                                "k": {
                                    "string": "TestAsset-Meta"
                                },
                                "v": {
                                    "map": [
                                        {
                                            "k": {
                                                "string": "name"
                                            },
                                            "v": {
                                                "string": "My-Cool_NFT"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "k": {
                                                "string": "image"
                                            },
                                            "v": {
                                                "string": "ipfs://Qme7ss3ARVgxv6rXqVPiikMJ8u2NLgmgszg13pYrDKEoiu"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "mint": {
        "tokens": [
            {
                "assets": [
                    {
                        "asset_name": "546573744173736574",
                        "fingerprint": "asset1q0skl97csmvgxtewd2jrrpvdzw4hyg83wcyee2",
                        "quantity": 1
                    }
                ],
                "policy_id": "2037e837ffb5536a8795f493ed14c1f91fc9130df3466386750168a1",
                "policy_script": {
                    "script": "policy_vkh17g7njq60dfrx76xyelltw69lff2c6md7y2guhmdflxm2jgywwgz",
                    "script_type": "native"
                }
            }
        ],
        "wallet_policy_key_hash": "policy_vkh15cnjur9ld37p9gznxafzs2jtqf4qpxlyhwhccwt9kktt53gt76u",
        "wallet_policy_key_index": "0H"
    },
    "outputs": [
        {
            "address": "addr_test1qql63uhskkchjsy74kjyx9tk8azsl9gfjxfk8rarnvsshn3sl2jjsnfkffuhuuug5vywcyh0704hpyldjrzjacts4qpqa40yu4",
            "amount": {
                "quantity": 499640671,
                "unit": "lovelace"
            },
            "assets": [],
            "derivation_path": [
                "1852H",
                "1815H",
                "0H",
                "0",
                "0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "address": "addr_test1qrf87vnetzcmf4vdzhpyatzr90c036xpzkhsdjp4y5as4c72wk6fknuew0vvy6s7jklr2c92t7uf3plyuqvcw390wywql37usz",
            "amount": {
                "quantity": 172400,
                "unit": "lovelace"
            },
            "assets": [
                {
                    "asset_name": "546573744173736574",
                    "policy_id": "2037e837ffb5536a8795f493ed14c1f91fc9130df3466386750168a1",
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "script_validity": "valid",
    "validity_interval": {
        "invalid_before": {
            "quantity": 0,
            "unit": "slot"
        },
        "invalid_hereafter": {
            "quantity": 68437663,
            "unit": "slot"
        }
    },
    "withdrawals": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand the BabbageOutputTooSmallUTxO to mean the output is from the tx is too small (ie. not enough input). The annoying thing is it worked well not that long ago

It might have worked in an earlier era (ie Alonzo) but my suspicion is that the rules have changed slightly for the new Babbage error.

The error message also gives the value of `172400` (in lovelace) as being too small and that value does appear in your transaction outputs. Again I suspect that value has increased slightly.

Comment: You were right. Thanks for the response

Comment: Does somebody know how to update the SDK? I would like to get documentations or something like this please <3

Answer (score 1):

Yes the calculation of the min UTxO value has changed which is explained [here](https://youtu.be/Tsp9F23dBiM?t=730). So Erik is correct!
I would try to update the library you're using to create your transaction, because whatever SDK or library you're using, I'd expect it to handle that change for you.

Comment: Thank you, I started using the beta version of the lib and it works now. I felt I had already tried it but anyway